# Thoughts on this approach for Controller and Presenter

Tags: design, architecture

[image: Controller and Presenter]

I would appreciate if you could point the flaws as well as any positives ( if there are any ) about this kind of approach. 
What's my problem?
Every request that comes, gets mapped to a specific controller and a specific method. Now, when a request comes, there are two options: **Display a view** for that request OR **call some Business Logic class**, that will do some BL action and then it might call the presenter to display a view, as a response to that BL action, or it might not.
I would use the DIP for the interaction between BL and Presenter. Would it make sense to do the same for Controller communication with Presenter? ( In my mind, the Controller would just need to know one method from Presenter that will result in displaying the view). 
I know that either way, the controller will need to "know" which view needs to be displayed. But at least i would separate displaying and formatting views from handling requests and calling/passing the request inwards to BL.
Note that I'm not really following specific rules of an architecture pattern, rather combining different in a pragmatic way.
Is there a better way to do this, am i completely of the mark here?

Comment: I'd recommend centralizing ownership of "Display a view" rather than splitting it between the Controller and Business Rules (BR). The BR can be called to decide what should go in the View, but the BR shouldn't generate the View.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach makes it harder to test the Business Logic (BL) layer without knowing the presenter / view layers.

I suggest to keep BL separate to return results to the controller. This way, you can test this in isolation.

The controller then uses this result to determine whether a presenter / which presenter to use.